# Javascript Front end - Evaluate string as expression - Alternative for using eval()

Tags: javascript, eval, frontend

I would like to evaluate a string as an expression in Javascript. I'm reading the string from a JSON which is dynamic. So, the expression can be anything. Here is the pseudo code I'm using

```
var formula = {
    "expression":"value * 9/5 + 32" //Dynamic JSON
}

var value = 26; // Dynamic value

var result = evaluateExpression(value, formula);

function evaluateExpression(value, formula) {
    return eval(formula.expression);
}
```

This is how I've been using eval(). Is there any other alternative to this? I've also considered using [Math.js](http://mathjs.org/), which I think is overkill for my requirements.

Comment: We don't know what you requirements *are* in the first place.

Comment: what is wrong with eval? it does what u need.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I just have to evaluate the dynamic string as expression. The sample string in the above example is "value * 9/5 + 32". This works fine. I just wanted to know if there's any alternate way to do this

Comment: @Rana
I've read that using eval() has some performance and security issues. Is this still a concern with modern browsers?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea

Comment: @Naveensanthosh and what's supposed to be in that "dynamic string"? What "expressions" are we talking about here?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: By "dynamic string", I mean that the string can change and is not the same one I've mentioned in the aforementioned example. For instance, "value * 9/5 + 32" is an expression

Comment: @Naveensanthosh I know what you meant by "dynamic string" and that's completely not what I asked about. I've also seen that example and understand that you consider that an expression, but I was asking for a more concrete requirements, not another example. Is `sin(5)` an expression? Is `[1,2,3].length` an expression? Are we talking about JS expressions, mathematical expression subset of it or, *what exactly*?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz  Apologies for the misunderstanding. I'm talking about mathematical expressions.

Comment: @Naveensanthosh In that case I think that Mathjs could be a solid choice. It has no external dependencies and will isolate your script from potential malicious input. At least should, I'd check that first.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `eval` would be to create a parser and evaluator in javascript. This is rather trivial, but a bit tedious. `eval` is mostly fine, unless you're going to evaluate strings provided by one user in the other user's browser. If this is the case, you'll have to write a parser (or generate it with a tool like PEG.js).

Comment: I'd say the difficulty of writing an intepreter varies vastly depending on the complication of the interpreted expression, but I'd never call it *trivial*.

Answer (score 0):

you could achieve the same using Function constructor

```js
var formula = {
    "expression":"value * 9/5 + 32" //Dynamic JSON
}

var value = 26; // Dynamic value

var result = evaluateExpression(value, formula);
alert(result);

function evaluateExpression(value, formula) {
    return (new Function( 'value', 'return (' + formula.expression + ')' )(value));
    //return eval(formula.expression);
}
```

Comment: Please add why this is better than `eval`

Comment: @Bergi the statements inside new Function runs in a new scope where eval runs in the current scope. If you update a local variable in the expression passed in eval. it will be updated. Also, it will be easier to keep track of the variables that may be used in the expression string by seperating them as parameters in the Function constructor